# Read and write multiple files files in python?

Tags: python

I wrote a code which read multiples ligand files and one receptor file and calculates the distance between XYZ coordinates of receptor and ligand files one by one. then want to write the output file for every specific ligand files separately. but my code just writing one output file and writing results for all the ligand files in one file.
Below is my code:

```
  import re
  import math
  import glob
      class Atom:
         def __init__(self, resname='', resnum='', atomid=0, chainId='', 
  x=0.0, y=0.0, z=0.0, atomname = '',  element = ''):
    self.x=x
    self.y = y
    self.z = z
    self.resname = resname
    self.resnum = resnum
    self.atomid = atomid
    self.chainid = chainId
    self.atomname = atomname
    self.element = element
    self.resnum = resnum

def __init__(self, line):
    self.x = line[28: 38].strip()
    self.y = line[39: 46].strip()
    self.z = line[47: 56].strip()
    self.resname = line[17: 21].strip()
    self.resnum = line[22: 28].strip()
    self.atomid = line[7: 12].strip()
    self.chainid = line[22]
    self.atomname = line[13: 16].strip()
    self.element = line[77:78]

def caluDistence(proteinatom, ligandatoms, cutoff = 4.0):
   matchedAtom = []
   for atom in proteinatom:
    atomX = float(atom.x)
    atomY = float(atom.y)
    atomZ = float(atom.z)
    for hetatom in ligandatoms:
        hetatomX = float(hetatom.x)
        hetatomY = float(hetatom.y)
        hetatomZ = float(hetatom.z)
        d = math.sqrt((atomX - hetatomX)**2  + (atomY - hetatomY)**2  + 
 (atomZ - hetatomZ)**2 )
        #print (str(d))
        if d <= cutoff:
            if atom in matchedAtom :
                continue
            matchedAtom.append(atom)
return matchedAtom
return d

pdb = "receptor.pdb"
lig = "D:\\python\\workspace\\practise\\exhau15\\frag1\\out_ligand_*.pdbqt"
files=glob.glob(lig)
proteinatom=[]
for line in open(pdb, 'r').readlines():
   if line[0:6] == 'ATOM  ':
    atom = Atom(line)
    proteinatom.append(atom)
ligandatoms = []
for file in files:
    print("current file :" +file)
    with open(file) as f:
            for line in f:
                if line[0:6] == 'ATOM  ':
                    atom = Atom(line)
                    ligandatoms.append(atom)
matchedAtomList = caluDistence(proteinatom, ligandatoms)
outfile = "out2.pdb"
output = open(outfile, 'w')
for atom in matchedAtomList:
  output.write("current file name:    " + file + "     "  + atom.resname + "  
  "   + atom.resnum + "        " + atom.element + '\n' )

   output.flush()
   output.close()
```

Comment: Too much code, please reduce this to a [mcve] please.

Comment: I think you need to place your `outfile="out2.pdb"` and `output = open(outfile,'w')` in the last for loop and assign a new name for each iteration, like: `outfile = "out" + str(index) + ".pdb"`.

Comment: yess its working now. The problem was i was not writing output file in the last loop.